# Let $f: A \to B$ and $g : B \to C$. Is it true that if $g$ is surjective, then $g\circ f$ is also surjective?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

> Let $f: A \to B$ and $g : B \to C$. Is it true that if $g$ is surjective, then $g\circ f$ is also surjective?

Since the surjectivity of $g$ only tells us that the cardinality of $B$ is greater than or equal to $C$ that doesn't necessarily imply that the same holds for $A$ and $C$ so it seems that the statement is not true? Any hints on how to show this formally?

Comment: It works the other way.  If $g \circ f$ is surjective, then $g$ is surjective.

Answer (score 1):

The statement is false. Choose, as a counterexample, $$f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R, \quad x\mapsto 0$$ and $$g: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R, \quad x\mapsto x.$$
(Obviously, $g$ is surjective, but $g\circ f: \mathbb R\to \mathbb R, x\mapsto 0$, is not.)

Answer (score 0):

It is not true. Let fx. $A=B=C=\mathbb{N}$ with $g(x)=x$ and $f(x)=1$.

However, if $f$ is surjective aswell, then $g\circ f$ is surjective.